# Table chart giving link button

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawVisualization2(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
            if (dataValues.length < 1)
                return;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
            data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[3]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[4]);
            data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[5]);
            data.addColumn('string', 'Email');


            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].Value1, dataValues[i].Value2, dataValues[i].Value3, dataValues[i].Value4, dataValues[i].Value5, dataValues[i].Value6, 'www.google.in']);
            }

            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '####%' });
            formatter.format(data, 5);

            var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="{6}">{4}</a>');
            formatter.format(data, [4, 6]); 

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5]);

            var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'Container1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': columnNames.split(',')[1],
                    'ui': {
                        'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
                        'allowTyping': false,
                        'allowMultiple': false,
                        'caption': categoryCaption,
                        'label': columnNames.split(',')[2]
                    }
                }
            });


            var table2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Table',
                'containerId': 'TableContainer2',

                'options': {
                    'width': '895px',
                    'page': 'enable',
                    'pageSize': 5

                }
            });

            new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample2')).bind([categoryPicker2], [table2]).draw(view, { allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true });
            //visualization.draw(view, { allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true });
        }

     </script>
```

I am facing a problem on table chart adding link button ;here is my code.And column 7 need to go google;First tried with simple table,it works fine;but in case of controls and dashboard ;its not i tried bur could can anyone help me to resolve.Thank you..

Comment: That looks mostly fine.  Just set the Table's `allowHtml` option to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

That looks mostly fine. Just set the Table's `allowHtml` option to `true`:

```
var table2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'TableContainer2',
    'options': {
        'width': '895px',
        'page': 'enable',
        'pageSize': 5,
        allowHtml: true
    }
});
```

Also, trying to set options in the Dashboard's `draw` call will not do anything, so remove the second argument:

```
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample2')).bind([categoryPicker2], [table2]).draw(view);
```

Comment: Still i am having same problem

Comment: Can you describe the problem in detail?

Comment: i am not able to see a table now;after adding link button;if i remove it will work fine;before that i tried,link button for simple table for that no problem

Comment: Open the page in Chrome and check the developer's console for error messages (ctrl+shift+j to open in windows).